# Disambiguation of friend and member binary operator

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, friend, ambiguous-call

Consider the following class with a binary operator (I use `operator+` just as an example).

```
struct B{};

template<class>
struct A{
    template<class BB>
    void operator+(BB const&) const{std::cout<<"member"<<std::endl;}
    template<class BB>
    friend void operator+(BB const&, A const&){std::cout<<"friend"<<std::endl;}
};
```

I can call this binary operator with two different types:

```
A<int> a;
B b;
a + b; // member
b + a; // friend
```

Then when I try to use `A` on both sides (`a + a`) a lot of strange things happen. Three compilers give different answer to the same code.

Some context: I don't want to define `void operator+(A const&)` because I need a template to SFINAE functions away if some syntax doesn't work. Also I don't want a `template<class BB, class AA> friend void operator(BB const&, AA const&)`. Because since `A` is a template, different instantiations will produce multiple definitions of the same template.

Continuing with the original code:

**Strange thing # 1:** In gcc, the friend takes precedence:

```
a + a; // prints friend in gcc
```

I expect the member to take precedence, **is there a way for the member to take precedence gcc?**

**Strange thing # 2:** In clang, this code doesn't compile:

```
a + a; // use of overload is ambiguous
```

This already points out at an inconsistency between gcc and clang, **who is right?** **What would be a workaround for clang that makes it work like gcc?**

If I try to be more greedy in the arguments, e.g. to apply some optimization I could use forwarding references:

```
struct A{
    template<class BB>
    void operator+(BB&&) const{std::cout<<"member"<<std::endl;}
    template<class BB>
    friend void operator+(BB&&, A const&){std::cout<<"friend"<<std::endl;}
};
```

**Strange thing # 3:** Using forwarding reference gives a warning in gcc,

```
a + a; // print "friend", but gives "warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:"
```

But still compiles, **How can I silence this warning in gcc or workaround?** Just as in case # 1, I expect to prefer the member function but here it prefers the friend function *and* gives a warning.

**Strange thing # 4:** Using forwarding reference gives an error in clang.

```
a + a; // error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous (with operand types 'A' and 'A')
```

Which again points at an inconsistency between gcc and clang, who is right in this case?

In summary, I am trying to make this code work consistently. I really want the function to be injected friend function (not free friend functions). I don't want to define a function with equal non-template arguments because different instantiation will produce duplicated declarations of the same functions.

---

Here is the full code to play with:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
struct B{};

template<class>
struct A{
    template<class BB>
    void operator+(BB const& /*or BB&&*/) const{cout<<"member\n";}
    template<class BB>
    friend void operator+(BB const& /*or BB const&*/, A const&){cout<<"friend\n";}
};

int main(){
    A<int> a;      //previos version of the question had a typo here: A a;
    B b;
    a + b; // calls member
    b + a; // class friend
    a + a; // surprising result (friend) or warning in gcc, hard error in clang, MSVC gives `member` (see below)

    A<double> a2; // just to instantiate another template
}
```

---

Note: I am using `clang version 6.0.1` and `g++ (GCC) 8.1.1 20180712`. According to Francis Cugler MSVS 2017 CE give yet a different behavior.

---

I found a workaround that does the correct thing (prints 'member' for `a+a` case) for both clang and gcc (for MSVS?), but it requires a lot for boiler plate and an artificial base class:

```
template<class T>
struct A_base{
    template<class BB>
    friend void operator+(BB const&, A_base<T> const&){std::cout<<"friend"<<std::endl;}
};

template<class T>
struct A : A_base<T>{
    template<class BB>
    void operator+(BB const&) const{std::cout<<"member"<<std::endl;}
};
```

However it still give an ambiguous call if I replace `BB const&` with `BB&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all ambiguous. There are known partial ordering bugs in GCC when ordering a member and a non-member, e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66914.

Just constrain your friend to not participate in overload resolution if `BB` is a specialization of `A`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you do such constraining? I tried with enable_if but it didn't help because the error happens before the function is eliminated.

Comment: That bug points to a duplicate https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53499 , this is around since 2012. It seems that there is no much interest. I would say that this feature is fundamental to implement algebraic types correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You want to disable the friend if BB is convertible to A:

```
template<
  class BB,
  std::enable_if<
    !std::is_convertible<B const&, A>::value, int>::type = 0>
friend void operator+(BB const&, A const&){std::cout<<"friend"<<std::endl;}
```

Note: you need to use the `std::enable_if` as the type to make it so that the function *declaration* never resolves if the SFINAE doesn't resolve.

Another hint is if you want to resolve to the member function if BB is merly castable to A (and not equal to A) you may want to provide a default type for the template:

```
template <typename BB = A>
void operator++(BB const&) const {/*...*/}
```

That is only really useful if you provide other opterator++'s to the class, but it is worth noting.

Comment: Would you constrain the friend or the member function?

Comment: It depends which you want selected. My gut is that you'll want to use the  use the member when BB==A, so you want to disable the friend function, but that it entirely up to you :-).

Another hint is you may want to have the member function be template <class BB=A>, which will help the member function resolve if BB is castable to A. I'll add that to my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking in the case in which the generic effect of the friend and the member is the same. That is, the case which is an arithmetic operation in which both have the same final effect but still the compilers requires the ambiguity to be resolved.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I am not sure if a default template argument helps with the deduction or to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: (in other words, the sad part of this workaround is that I don't even want to change behavior but just disambiguate a benign ambiguity. I don't know why the member function wouldn't be preferred at this point and be done with it, as apparently MSVS would do, according to the other answer).

Comment: Welcome to c++, there is no such thing as benign ambiguity :-P.

I can guess (and only guess) that friend "promotes" the friend operator to be a member function of BB. If BB is AA, then you'll have 2 choices for A{}+A{}, each having to figure out one template argument, so they both are weighed as the same. If I was a standard's expert I'd cite why one should be chosen over the other. But I'm just a programmer - if things are ambiguous enough for the *compiler* to be weird, then people maintaining this code certainly won't understand it. Better to be explicit, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I mean by "benign ambiguity" is that (for this particular case) I could live with compilers or standard deciding that either the member or friend have higher priority (as MSVS does apparently). I think it makes sense that the member function should have priority (be a better match), but again, I can go with either one. Now, with gcc and clang is the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

I went and ran your code in Visual Studio 2017 CE  as:

```
int main(){
    A<int> a;
    B b;
    a + b; // calls member
    b + a; // class friend
    a + a; // surprising result or warning in gcc, hard error in clang
}
```

And Visual Studio compiled without errors, and ran successfully without warnings and when the program returned it exited with a code of `(0)` with this output:

```
member
friend
member
```

I've tried this with float, double, char and got the same results.

Even as an extra test I added this after the template class above:

```
/* your code here */

struct C {};

int main() {
    A<C> a;
    B b;
    a + b;
    b + a;
    a + a;

    return 0;
}
```

And still got the same results.

---

As for the later part of your question that pertains to `Strange thing #1, #2, #3, #4:` that pertains to both `gcc` & `clang`

I did not have this issue with Visual Studio as `a + a` was giving me a `member` for the output and the member was taking precedence over the friend overload. Now as for the fact of operator precedence I don't know off the top of my head if `GCC` and `Clang` will differ from `Visual Studio` as each compiler works differently and I'm not real familiar with them but as for the language itself your compiler doesn't know what to do with `A::+()` when it doesn't know what kind of `<type>` to be using. However it knows what to do when you have `A<int>::+()` or `A<char>::+()` or `A<C>::+()`...

Comment: Yes, sorry, it didn't copy the `<int>` in `A<int>` in the example. I corrected it now, so you can remove the first part of your answer. In any case, MSVC shows a third behavior (and the one we expected).

Comment: I modified your answer to remove the part that was caused by my mistake.

Comment: @alfC Not a problem and thank you for the assistance!