# Ambiguous operator<< overloading in Clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code does not compile in clang 3.5+, but compiles in all gcc versions and clang < 3.5.

```
struct Logger {
    template <class T>
    Logger& operator<<(const T& /*val*/)
    {
        // m_buf << val;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Value {
    template <class Stream>
    friend Stream& operator<<(Stream& os, const Value& /*val*/)
    {
        // os << m_val;
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Logger logger;
    Value value;
    logger << value;
    return 0;
}
```

The clang error is

```
<source>:23:12: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Logger' and 'Value')

    logger << value;

    ~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~

<source>:3:13: note: candidate function [with T = Value]

    Logger& operator<<(const T& /*val*/)

            ^

<source>:12:20: note: candidate function [with Stream = Logger]

    friend Stream& operator<<(Stream& os, const Value& /*val*/)

                   ^
```

Who is correct according to the standard, clang or gcc?
If clang, how do I properly write a logger with "<<" that redirects any value supporting "<<" to another stream?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793199/disambiguation-of-friend-and-member-binary-operator
probably duplicate

Comment: Use SFINAE (or concepts!) to restrict the standalone `operator<<` to `std::basic_stream<>` instantiations.

Comment: @Harry, m_val is a different type (some internal representation of Value), no recursion here

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. does not work for non-std::basic_stream stream-like objects (like other loggers)

Comment: @Harry yes, the commented line should be `os << val.m_val;` or something like that, which is irrelevant to the topic

Comment: Well of course it doesn't. Either `Value` implements printing to stream-like objects, or stream-like objects do that. Both at the same time cannot, that's ambiguous. You need to exclude one or the other from the overload set.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. but this compiles in gcc. First it calls Value's friend function and then Logger's operator<<

Comment: It's a gcc bug. Can you explain why it prefers Value's friend function? There is no reason to do that in the standard. Neither the friend nor the member are better than the other.